# \reuseMPgraphic with changing texts passed from ConTeXt?

Tags: context, metapost

In my presentations, I am often filling pyramides with different texts boxed in a verticaly centered, middle aligned frame. I have an environment with a template defined with `\startuseMPgraphic` in which I pass external macros.

```
\setuppapersize [S3]

\defineframedtext [Cadre] [align={middle,lohi}]
\startusableMPgraphic{test}
label ("\Cadre{\Legende{}}", origin);
\stopusableMPgraphic

\startreusableMPgraphic{Test}
label ("\Cadre{\Legende{}}", origin);
\stopreusableMPgraphic


\starttext
\def\Legende{hello}

\useMPgraphic{test}    
\reuseMPgraphic{Test}    

\def\Legende{world}

\useMPgraphic{test} %this is what I want but AFAIK will be calculated at each run
\reuseMPgraphic{Test} %output is not what I want

\stoptext
```

Since my presentations are very long (up to 100 pages and more), I would like to avoid calculing those graphs at each compilation. I cannot use `\startreusableMPgraphic` and `\reuseMPgraphic`, because text isn't changed. 
I understand changing strings within metapost doesn't help neither, because of boxes. What is the trick to have those graphs only compiled once, but with the proper texts?

Comment: What you are asking for is a contradiction in itself.  You only want to compile the figure once but have it change on every invocation.  That is logically impossible.  What you could do instead is render that background graphic once as a `reusableMPgraphic` and then draw labels on top of that in a `usableMPgraphic`.  This will require some manual work though.

Comment: Alternatively you can have a `reusableMPgraphic` for each label text, i.e. if you request the figure twice with the exact same label text, you only have to render it once.

Comment: But then again, MP is extremely fast, so there is not really a reason for caching (unless you typeset things like the MetaFun manual with thousands of MP graphics).

Comment: @Henri Menke. My question may be also related with a misunderstanding of MetaFun manual. Is a `useMPgraphic` recompiled each time I make a change to the source elsewhere (for example adding a sentence to another slide)?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  A `usableMPgraphic` is recompiled on every invocation of `\useMPgraphic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the static elements of you graphic in a `reusableMPgraphic` which you then include in your `usableMPgraphic`.  This requires some manual work though, because you will not be able to reference material from the static part in the dynamic part.

I've put some dumb logging into place so that you can see in the terminal how many times each graphic is rendered.

```
\setuppapersize [S3]

\defineframedtext [Cadre] [align={middle,lohi}]

% This will only be rendered once
\startreusableMPgraphic{static}
  label("\Cadre{}", origin);

  % Print something to the terminal to show how many times we are rendering
  message("Rendering static") ;
\stopreusableMPgraphic

\startusableMPgraphic{dynamic}
  draw textext("\reuseMPgraphic{static}") ;
  label(\MPstring{Legende}, origin) ;

  % Print something to the terminal to show how many times we are rendering
  message("Rendering dynamic") ;
\stopusableMPgraphic


\starttext

\setMPtext{Legende}{hello}
\useMPgraphic{dynamic}

\setMPtext{Legende}{world}
\useMPgraphic{dynamic}

\stoptext
```

In the log you should see

```
metapost        > message : Rendering static
metapost        > message : Rendering dynamic
metapost        > message : Rendering dynamic
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know the `\MPstring` macro, which will be very helpful.